# File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml not found

Tags: android, android-support-library

I got an error whith my application on API Level 19 (Kit Kat). I implemented the android support Library 24.0.0 and started my activity and get the following error:

```
Exception while inflating <vector>
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
```

further down in stack trace there is something like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ironicdev.android.openleaf/ironicdev.android.openleaf.ui.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

and then

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
```

(I didnt want to post the complete stack trace).

I found some solutions on google, like to set "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" in my gradle file. But it didn't help. I select "clean Project" in the menu bar, but nothing.

I also deleted all my vector xml files and replaced it with png files. But the error is still there.

If I start on API 21 and higher, all is fine.

What should I do now?

Edit: here is my xml code from MainActivty (where the error is thrown)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/extended_app_bar_main" />

        <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard_diagram" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:text="@string/tv_newest_entries" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_newest_entries"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

extended_app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_simple_search"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontInverted"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_simple_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/colorFontInverted"
            android:hint="@string/hint_simple_search" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_simple_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_magnify_white_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:theme="@style/Accent.Button"
        android:text="@string/btn_advanced_search"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

content_dashboard_diagram.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/pie_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u post u r xml  code ?

Comment: I edit my question with my code

Comment: *If I start on API 21 and higher, all is fine* -- Right... Because that resource that can't be found and is only available if you compile with SDK 21+

Comment: so, what should I do to avoid the error and make my app startable with API 19? I never used this resource

Comment: Increase the `compileSdkVersion`. It is the `targetSdkVersion` that determines the "max" API of device that you can use.

Comment: And, you don't explicitly use that resource, no. The `Toolbar` class does.

Comment: compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are already set to 24. MinSdkVersion is 19. buildToolsVersion is 22.0.1

Comment: Always prefer same buildToolsVersion as complieSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Comment: thanks @Kathi! That solved my problem. Now the app starts correctly!

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem a few days ago.

Make sure all of your activities themes extend from Theme.AppCompat and this should be fixed

I've created an issue on the official tracker that explains the problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219724